# From a list of tuples containing names and id , i want tuples which contains names and list of names which got the similiar id

Tags: haskell

```
datatest :: [(Maybe String,Integer)]
datatest = [(Just "name1" , 111), (Just "name2" , 222), (Nothing, 333), (Just "name4",111)]
```

need the output like this

```
[(Just "name1",[Just "name1",Just "name4"]),(Just "name2",[Just "name2"]),(Nothing,[]),(Just "name4", [Just "name1",Just "name4"])]
```

In test123, it takes a list of tuples containing (Maybe Name, Id) and giving [(Maybe Name, [Maybe Name])] in here the list of names are the names with similar id

```
test123 :: [(Maybe String, Integer)] -> [(Maybe String,[Maybe String])]
test123 rows = 
  fmap (\(name,id) -> 
                DL.foldl' (\(rowAcc,nameAcc) (fname,fid) -> 
                                    case (id,fid) of
                                      (val1,val2) ->  if(val1==val2)
                                                        then (fname,(nameAcc++[name]) )
                                                      else (fname,nameAcc)
                                      (Nothing , _) -> (fname,nameAcc)          
                  ) ("",[]) rows
    ) rows
```

This is the code i had written, but I'm getting compilation errors.

Below are the errors I'm getting at compile time:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘Maybe t0’
      Expected type: [(Maybe String, Maybe t0)]
        Actual type: [(Maybe String, Integer)]
    • In the third argument of ‘DL.foldl'’, namely ‘rows’

error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘Maybe t0’
      Expected type: [(Maybe String, Maybe t0)]
        Actual type: [(Maybe String, Integer)]
    • In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘rows’
```

Comment: If your matching names with ids, wouldn't it be better to have `[(id, [Maybe Name])]` instead of `[(Maybe Name, [Maybe Name])]`?

Answer (score 4):

The particular error you're asking about occurs because of this part:

```
                                case (id,fid) of
                                  (val1,val2) ->  if(val1==val2)
                                                    then (fname,(nameAcc++[name]) )
                                                  else (fname,nameAcc)
                                  (Nothing , _) -> (fname,nameAcc)
--                                 ^^^^^^^
```

`id` is an `Integer`, but you're trying to pattern match it against `Nothing`, which is a `Maybe something`.

This `case` branch makes no sense. It's also unreachable because `(val1,val2)` before it always matches (it cannot fail), so we can simply remove the `Nothing` pattern:

```
                                case (id,fid) of
                                  (val1,val2) ->  if(val1==val2)
                                                    then (fname,(nameAcc++[name]) )
                                                  else (fname,nameAcc)
```

But why use `case` at all? All we're really doing is bind `id` to `val1` and `fid` to `val2`. We could just use the original variables and get rid of the `case` entirely:

```
                                if(val1==val2)
                                   then (fname,(nameAcc++[name]) )
                                   else (fname,nameAcc)
```

We can remove some redundant parens:

```
                                if val1==val2
                                   then (fname,nameAcc++[name])
                                   else (fname,nameAcc)
```

... and pull out common parts:

```
                                (fname, if val1 == val2
                                            then nameAcc++[name]
                                            else nameAcc)
```